# How to get Response Headers node value in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, header, header-files, payload

I want to get the Response Headers node value in the XSLT file.
[XSLT File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiJsB.png)

In the above image XSLT atom1 file, I want to access the **X-Pages** value.

Like: `<XPagesValue>1</XPagesValue>`

For this, I tried with below code, to get the X-page value in another XSLT atom, but, with this below line's, I'm unable to get the X-Pages value.

```
<XPagesValue>
<xsl:value-of select="//vpf:Payload[./@Role='C' and ./@id='atom1']"></xsl:value-of>
</XPagesValue>
```

Can you please help me out, to get the X-Pages value.

Thanks,
Chenna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficient way to write your XPATH is as following:

```
<XPagesValue>
        <xsl:value-of select="//vpf:Payload[@Role='C' and @id='atom1']/vpf:http.header/vpf:http.header.info[@id='X-Pages']/@value" />
    </XPagesValue>
```

You will get the output of X-Pages value.

Comment: Hi Vebbie, thanks for your prompt replay. Using your lines, I'm unable to get the X-Pages values. I'm getting empty tag '<XPagesValue/>' only.

Comment: I created sample XML like this from yours. `<Payload Role='C' id='atom1'>
 <http.header>
  <http.header.info id="X-Pages" value="4"/>
 </http.header>
</Payload>`   And it is working in my local box. Can you check for the spelling of all nodes and attributes ?

Comment: Hi Vebbie, I tried with your code, with proper spelling, even tho I'm not able to get the X-Pages Value. At least, I'm unable to get the header details with(<xsl:value-of select="//vpf:Payload[@Role='C' and @id='atom1']/http.header" />. Is any another way?

Comment: You can check the correct use of namespace in XPATH. And meanwhile try out this  `<xsl:value-of select="//vpf:Payload[@Role='C' and @id='atom1']/vpf:http.header/vpf:http.header.info[@id='X-Pages']/@value" />`... I have added namespace to each node in the hierarchy

Comment: Hi Vebbie, your above code is working fine, now I can get the X-Pages values. Thanks for your efforts and Time. Please update your answer with the above line.